# invalid_account_type in rclone to dropbox

Tags: dropbox, rclone

We currently need to send large files to a dropbox. We're using `rclone` to do this. *We are using the trial period from dropbox advanced.*

When we try to send by `rclone` using the api, the console reports:

> "invalid_account_type/feature", as we can see from the documentation (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/data-transport-limit).

When we try to report this to dropbox support, often says this message is due to the exceeded limit of "data transport api" calls" which is 1 million api calls. For us is quite suspicious because we start trial period in less than 1 week and send reasonable size files.

Before we found orientation to add flag `"--dropbox-chunk-size"`. Just to explain, we did several chunk size upload change tests which was the suggestion made by the `rclone` forums before.

Would you be able to help and guide us in solving this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that you're getting that `invalid_account_type/feature` error, but you believe you shouldn't be? In that case, would you be able to post the API request and response for reference? (Be sure to redact the access token though.)

Comment: Only today we see the message: invalid_account_type/feature. The dropbox support answer us today but for us we guess not possible exceeded 1 million apis in few days. My shift ended today, tomorrow i will confirm token configuration.

Comment: I recommend printing out the full HTTPS request and response, including both headers and bodies, if possible. Don't post the access token though.